# How to get 2 images to appear/disappear while being inline

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 speech bubbles and I want them to appear first on the left of the dog (blue one), then 2 seconds later the brown one should appear on the right side of the dog. I'm doing many CSS elements at once and they are conflicting with each other.

**One:** the 3 images should all be aligned in the order shown (the brown one is not up far enough, why?)

**Two:** all three images should be centered (having trouble with setting margins left and right to auto, which is what is recommended for centering, but they end up on top of each other).

**Three:** using jQuery, I want to fade in the left, blue speech bubble, and then 2 seconds later, the blue one fades out, then 0.5 seconds later the brown one on the right should fade in.

**Some problems I'm having:** 
- the images are on top of each other 
- when blue one fades out, it "jumps" the other two images out of place
- currently the brown speech bubble is not high enough

For context, I'm using HTML/CSS/jQuery with Razor. Thank you for your help.

[image]

**HTML**

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Logout";
    }

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Login.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Student.css" />

    <!--
        <script>
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            // Move to a new location or you can do something else
            window.location.href = "../Portal/Login";
        }, 4000);

    </script>

    -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".speech-bubble2").css("display", "none");
            $(".speech-bubble2").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
            $(".speech-bubble2").css("display", "inline-block");
        });
    </script>


    <div class="background">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h1 class="student-header" align="center">Later!</h1>
            <div id="studentnavicons">
                <a href="~/Student/Default" title="Store"><i class="fas fa-store-alt"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Student/Community" title="Community"><i class="fas fa-map-signs"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Student/Market" title="Marketplace"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Student/Avatar" title="Avatar"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
                <a href="~/Portal/Logout" title="Logout"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
            </div>

            <p class="student-text-medium">You are logged out!<br />Redirecting to login screen...</p>
            <div class="dog-container">
                <img class="dog" id="dog-pic" src="~/Content/

img/wasabi.png" />
            <img class="speech-bubble" id="dog-pic" src="~/Content/img/speech-bubble-blue.png" />

            <img class="speech-bubble2" id="dog-pic" src="~/Content/img/speech-bubble-fab.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*----------------Logout---------------*/
.dog-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 550px;
}

    .dog-container .dog {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-right: auto;
        z-index: 0;
    }

.speech-bubble {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 800px;
    width: 400px;

}

.speech-bubble2 {
    margin-left: 1200px;
    width: 400px;
}

/*---------------Logout END-------------*/
```

Comment: This line - `$(".speech-bubble2").css("display", "inline-block");` will cause the second speech bubble to display immediately.

Comment: Thanks @fubar. I removed that. Main problem is that it's too low. Not sure how to raise it up. :/

Comment: I would suggest using absolute positioning, relative to the `.dog-container`.

Comment: Darn, absolute positioning in `.dog-container` only made the footer go way up. The position of the images stayed the same.

Comment: No, you apply absolute positioning to the `.speech-bubble` elements, and relative positioning to the `.dog-container` element.

Comment: That helped the brown bubble move up, thanks! Now the blue speech bubble in on top of the dog face, the brown one is where it should be.

I changed the order of the images to: blue, dog, brown in the HTML. I also changed all 3 image margins to `margin:auto;`. I tried to add a `margin:right;` to the blue image first, but it was not reacting to any margin code, so I just changed them all to auto. But still have the blue bubble on the dog face.

Comment: I changed the image to show the current state.

Comment: Can you add a working snippet that illustrates the problem to your question?

Comment: I changed some of the margins and it happened to work out. So your suggestion actually was the biggest change to facilitate the others ones. If you wanted to add that as an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInrval function to continue the process of hiding and showing two speech bubble alternatively . Use a flag variable to keep track of which bubble to show or hide . The code will be something like following:

```
var flag=0;
$('#speech_bubble1').show();
$('#speech_bubble2').hide();

setInterval(function()
{
    if(flag==0)
    {
        $('#speech_bubble1').hide();
        $('#speech_bubble2').show();
        flag=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#speech_bubble2').hide();
        $('#speech_bubble2').show();
        flag=0;
    }


},2000);
```